# How do I integrate angular 6 and spring MVC with single server?

Tags: java, angular6

Angular 6 dist file is imported into the webapp folder.In the dispatcher servlet mapping the url pattern / is working for the REST api calls and the url pattern /** is used for index.html files. What url pattern is to be used for accessing both angular 6 & REST apis.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Generally your root path so `/` should serve the static content and then you have a path like `/api/*` reserved for rest services. You can do this by putting `server.contextPath=/api/*` in `application.properties` or `server.servlet.context-path` if you are using spring boot 2.0.0. And the you just put all the static content in one of the folders:

- /META-INF/resources/
- /resources/
- /static/
- /public/